# jQuery horizontal aligned div is not centered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got a div with `width:50%` and a text 
 With jQuery I determine both widths.

Then I tried to horizontal align the text within the div with this jQuery:

```
var wrapperWidth = $("#wrapper").width();
var textWidth = $("#text").width();
var horAlign = wrapperWidth / 2 - textWidth;
$("#text").css("margin-left", horAlign);
```

As you can see I did it like with `margin-left: calc(mydiv - mytext)` in CSS.
But the problem is, that the text is not centered.
Here's a fiddle:

```js
var r = (function () {
  var wrapperWidth = $("#wrapper").width();
  var textWidth = $("#text").width();
  var horAlign = wrapperWidth / 2 - textWidth;
  $("#text").css("margin-left", horAlign);
  
  var textHeight = $("#text").height();
  var vertAlign = textHeight / 2
  $("#text").css("margin-top", - vertAlign);
});

$(document).ready(r);
$(window).resize(r);
```

```css
#wrapper{
  width:50%;
  height:400px;
  border:solid 5px black;
  margin:auto;
  margin-top:50px;
}

#text{
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-size:3.5em;
  padding-left:30px;
  padding-right:30px;
  background:white;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
   <p id="text">Test</p>
</div>
```

Whats did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your calculation as below:

`var horAlign = wrapperWidth / 2 - textWidth / 2;`

What's more, delete `padding`, because it affects the aligning

```js
var r = (function () {
  var wrapperWidth = $("#wrapper").width();
  var textWidth = $("#text").width();
  var horAlign = wrapperWidth / 2 - textWidth / 2;
  $("#text").css("margin-left", horAlign);
  
  var textHeight = $("#text").height();
  var vertAlign = textHeight / 2
  $("#text").css("margin-top", - vertAlign);
});

$(document).ready(r);
$(window).resize(r);
```

```css
#wrapper{
  width:50%;
  height:400px;
  border:solid 5px black;
  margin:auto;
  margin-top:50px;
}

#text{
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-size:3.5em;
  //padding-left:30px;
  //padding-right:30px;
  background:white;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
   <p id="text">Test</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I need that padding, so there is a bit of whitespace between the line and the text. I just added - 30 to the jQuery like this: `wrapperWidth / 2 - textWidth / 2 - 30;` works perfect like that. Thanks :)

Comment: Yea, that also works. The point is to not forget taking `padding` into account :)

Comment: Yeah. I did forget it first. Too early in the morning I think ;)

Answer (score 2):

Why not a CSS only solution!?

```css
#wrapper{
  width:50%;
  height:400px;
  border:solid 5px black;
  margin:auto;
  margin-top:50px;
}

#text{
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-size:3.5em;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

#text span {
  position: relative;
  top: -35px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left:30px;
  padding-right:30px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="text"><span>Test</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not using css only, because it's going to be used with a CMS. So the user can edit the text and its size. And with your code, the text isn't vertically aligned to that top border. But nice solution tho :)

Comment: @TobiasGlaus it will also work with different text sizes! You better try.. The vertically alignment can be what ever you want it to be is just change `top: -35px;` to whatever you need.

Comment: @TobiasGlaus see fiddle with different amounts of text https://jsfiddle.net/aox302cz/

Comment: Yes. I know that, but thats not dynamic. Since the user can change the font-size the CSS `top` property will not automatically be adjusted

Comment: @TobiasGlaus You could fix that with setting the line height accordingly...

Answer (score 2):

Have edited your script a bit, And your text has padding so to calculate the width of the text including the padding you should use innerWidth() function.
Hope this helps :)

```js
var r = (function () {
  var wrapperWidth = $("#wrapper").width() / 2;
  var textWidth = $("#text").innerWidth() / 2;
  var horAlign = wrapperWidth - textWidth;
  $("#text").css("margin-left", horAlign);
  
  var textHeight = $("#text").height();
  var vertAlign = textHeight / 2
  $("#text").css("margin-top", - vertAlign);
});

$(document).ready(r);
$(window).resize(r);
```

```css
#wrapper{
  width:50%;
  height:400px;
  border:solid 5px black;
  margin:auto;
  margin-top:50px;
}

#text{
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-size:3.5em;
  padding-left:30px;
  padding-right:30px;
  background:white;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
   <p id="text">Test</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Beautiful solution aswell. Didn't think of using innerWidth() :D

Answer (score 1):

What you missd here is that you need ro divide textWidth by 2:

```
var horAlign = wrapperWidth/2 - textWidth/2; // please change your code to this.
```

Comment: Silly me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do something like that:

```
var wrapperWidth = $("#wrapper").width();
var textWidth = $("#text").width();
var paddings = 60;
var horAlign = (wrapperWidth - textWidth - paddings)/ 2 ;
```

and remember about paddings! var padding = 60;

Answer (score 0):

`width()` gives you the width excluding the padding. So you gotta modify your calculation to account for padding too like this:

and also the center aligning formula would be different

```js
var r = (function() {
  var wrapperWidth = $("#wrapper").width();
  var textWidth = $("#text").width() + parseInt($('#text').css('padding-left')) + parseInt($('#text').css('padding-right'));

  var horAlign = (wrapperWidth / 2) - (textWidth / 2);

  $("#text").css("margin-left", horAlign);

  var textHeight = $("#text").height();
  var vertAlign = textHeight / 2
  $("#text").css("margin-top", -vertAlign);
});

$(document).ready(r);
$(window).resize(r);
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  height: 400px;
  border: solid 5px black;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#text {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 3.5em;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <p id="text">Test</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I prefer using `innerWidth()`. That includes the padding.